# Is there a Common Format for Auto Id's?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The auto id's generated by an Android client in a Firestore collection seem to all meet certain criteria for me:

- 20 characters of length
- Start with a `-` dash
- Seem to cycle through characters based on time?

With the last point I mean that the first characters will look very similar if the creation happened in a similar time frame, e.g. `-LZ..`, `-L_..`, and `-La..`. This describes the [*Flutter* implementation](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/1aef7d92e9e77e929ad767320e3f96cbb26efacc/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/utils/push_id_generator.dart#L33).

However, looking at the [Javascript implementation of auto id](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/4f446f0a1c00f080fb58451b086efa899be97a08/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L30), I would assume that the only common criterion of all clients is the length of **20 characters**. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: What you're describing in bullet points sounds like Realtime Database push IDs, not Firestore generated document IDs.  What you're linking to is Firestore.

Comment: Also it might be helpful to say why you need to know this - are you planning on writing some code that's dependent on whatever generates one of these IDs?

Comment: Yeah, it's totally up to the client to decide what it wants to do for these IDs.  The server doesn't care.  You could generate your own, if you want.  I'm not sure how using a security rule is going to make things any better for you.  It's just a random ID, meant to be random enough that there is virtually no chance of collision with other IDs.

Comment: "Security rules should depend on it." Actually, they shouldn't. Push IDs (and other auto-generated IDs) should be treated as opaque identifiers. Any meaning you infer from them, might break at some point. That said: if you're curious how the Realtime Database generates its push IDs (that currently start with `-L`), see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accross all clients, the *auto id has a **length of 20 characters***:

- [iOS](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/14dd9dc2704038c3bf702426439683cee4dc941a/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/util/autoid.cc#L30)
- [Android](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/a024da69daa0a5264b133d9550d1cf068ec2b3ee/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/Util.java#L35)
- [JavaScript (Web)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/4f446f0a1c00f080fb58451b086efa899be97a08/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L29)
- [Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/utils/push_id_generator.dart#L50)

Answer (score 4):

You're referring to two types of IDs:

1. The push IDs as they are generated by the Firebase Realtime Database SDK when you call `DatabaseReference.push()` (or `childByAutoId` in iOS). These are described in [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html), and a JavaScript implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11).
2. The auth IDs that are generated by the Cloud Firestore SDK when you call `add(..)` or `doc()` (without arguments). The JavaScript implementation of this can indeed be found in the [Firestore SDK repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/4f446f0a1c00f080fb58451b086efa899be97a08/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L24-L34).

The only things these two IDs have in common is that they're designed to ensure enough entropy that realistically they will be globally unique, and that they're both 20 characters long.

Comment: No, I was referring to the **Cloud Firestore** implementation for Flutter.